# Change CSS style of parent element

Tags: html, css

This might has been answered already, though I couldn't find a concrete answer to my situation. I wrote the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">   
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   background-color: red;
}

.child {
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   background-color: blue;
}

.child:hover .parent {
   width: 75px;
}
```

As you might have noticed, I am trying to change the style of a parent element and this, ofcourse, is a wrong method of trying to achieve that. Can anyone show me an example of how I can make this possible? I also made a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u62bhno0/)

Comment: You can't do it! It's not possible to target parent selector in CSS

Comment: It's not possible to alter the parent div via child div css using only css

Comment: So I should probably make use of javascript here? Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: There is no parent selector in CSS but what is the real world scenario here? When you `hover` a child, its parent is also hovered on and so maybe it is possible by directly setting the properties on `.parent:hover`. This will work as long as the parent and child have same dimensions.

Comment: No, the problem is I am trying to make a menu with a submenu, however I styled the anchor element's background above the submenu (which is an unordered list element). Whenever I add styling to a situation like: .subMenu:hover, the styling won't be applied to the anchor above.